# Having trouble with \includegraphics

Tags: graphics

I am a new-comer to latex, so I know that there may be a simple fix to this but I can't figure it out on my own. I'm using the following code to try to put a picture in my document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{slide_20.jpg}
     \caption{Here is my image}
     \label{image-myimage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File 'slide_20.jpg' not found.
```

I have saved the picture in the same folder as the .tex document. I'm working in TeXworks on a mac. I have tried it with multiple pictures and it never works.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You don't even need to type the extension (unless there are files with the same name and another extension). Did you update recently?

Comment: You should not use `[h]` as a placement specifier only! This might result in pretty bad placement especially with large figures. You should use something like `[htbp]` (only `[h]` most likely gets replaced by `[ht]` throwing a warning), but with big figures you should always include the `[p]` option, too. This way LaTeX tries to use `h` if that's not possible or results in very bad spacing it tries the next from the list and so on. `p` is necessary because if you use large figures it might happen that this one and all following figures are moved to the end of the document or chapter!

Comment: Also, if you intend to use the same placement specifier for all figures, you might as well set the default to the desired value. This is done with `\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\fps@figure}{htbp}\makeatother`. The same is possible for tables using `\fps@table`.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct extension? Perhaps the file is called `*.jpeg` and not `*.jpg`. Have you included the `graphicx` package in your preamble? We could help you more and better if you would post a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)!

Comment: I completed your example to a document that people can test, can you show the log file you get from that, and the directory list?

Comment: @Skillmon The problem is less with the placement and more that it won't compile at all. I've tried both extensions (and without an extension) and included the graphicx package in my preamble.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure what those things are. How would I find them?

Comment: every time you run latex on `file.tex` it makes a `file.log` as well as `file.pdf` place the contents of `file.log`  for the above test file in the question so we can see why it fails for you

Comment: @S.Frank the placement stuff was not because this is the issue. I wrote that stuff because you said you're new to LaTeX just as information.

Comment: Just a wild guess, try to remove the underscore (_) and use `slide20.jpg` instead (change the actual file name too of course).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner That shouldn't be a problem, though. It usually works fine. (Spaces are different.)